# awk - Rounding all floating-point numbers in multi-line text file

Tags: awk, floating-point, printf, rounding

Assume a multi-line text file that contains multiple floating-point numbers as well as alphanumeric strings and special characters per line. The only consistency is that all floats are separated from any other string by a single whitespace. Further, assume that we wish to round **each** floating-point number to a maximum of *n* digits after the comma. All strings other than the floats shall remain **in place** and **as is**. Let us assume that n=5.

I know this can be implemented via *awk* easily. My current code (below) only rounds the last float of each line and swallows all strings that precede it. How do I improve it?

```
echo -e "\textit{foo} & 1234.123456 & -1234.123456\n1234.123456" |\
  awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++);printf("%.05f\n",$NF)}'
# -1234.12346
# 1234.12346
```

Comment: Look at the `;` you put in to terminate the `for` loop and really think about what that does to the printf after it!

Comment: @EdMorton Can you please clarify. To me, it seems correct: initialization at 1 (`i=1`), termination at NF (`i<=NF`), post-increment (`i++`)

Comment: The body of the loop (which is between the closing parenthesis and the semicolon) is empty. The `printf()` is outside the loop.

Comment: Your code expanded is `for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { do nothing }; printf("%.05f\n",$NF)`

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for the explanation! Let me ponder about this. This example should be simple enough for me to figure out.

Comment: Sounds good and please add the expected output. It'd also be good if you used `printf` to generate the input rather than `echo` since `echo` is non-portable and will produce different output on different machines and so we're guessing about what the input to awk actually will be given the `echo` in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
$ printf '\textit{foo} & 1234.123456 & -1234.123456\n1234.123456\n' |
  awk -F'[ ]' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i+0 == $i) $i = sprintf("%.05f",$i)} 1'
        extit{foo} & 1234.12346 & -1234.12346
1234.12346
```

`if ($i+0 == $i)` is the idiomatic awk way to test for a value being a number since only a number could have the same value on the left and right side of that comparison.

I'm setting the `FS` to a literal, single blank char instead of it's default which, confusingly, is also a blank char but the latter (i.e. `' '` vs `'[ ]'`) is treated specially and results in ALL chains of contiguous white space being treated as a separator and ignoring stripping leading/trailing blanks on a recompilation of `$0` (e.g. as caused by assigning to any field) and so would not allow your formatting to be maintained in the output.

Answer (score 1):

One solution :

```
$ echo -e "\textit{foo} & 1234.123456 & -1234.123456\n1234.123456" |
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if ($i ~ /[0-9]+.[0-9]+/){printf "%.05f\n", $i}}}'
```

### Output :

```
1234.12346
-1234.12346
1234.12346
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can all non-floats be maintained in place?

Comment: See my other answer with perl

Answer (score 1):

Using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) :

```
perl -i -pe 's/(\d+\.\d+)/sprintf "%.05f", $1/eg' file
```